# Saving both Xaml and InkCanvas to image in UWP app

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-10

I need a way to save both Xaml and `InkCanvas` to image.

If I try to save a `FrameworkElement` using `RenderTargetBitmap` class, then the content of InkCanvas is not saving.

I can use `await inkCanvas.InkPresenter.StrokeContainer.SaveAsync(stream);` to succeed with saving InkCanvas's content, but the underlying UI will no be saved.

What is the correct way to save the content of my app with some drawings over it (prodided by InkCanvas control)?

Comment: What is your saving via RenderTargetBitmap code?

Comment: [Save to image using RenderTargetBitmap](http://loekvandenouweland.com/content/save-xaml-as-png-in-a-windows-store-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the inking in InkCanvas is not done on the XAML layer, but instead in a Win2D layer, you'll need to use Win2D to draw the InkCanvas strokes out as an image and then layer that image with your XAML-based RenderTargetBitmap.

Mike Taulty has a pretty good discussion of a solution here

http://mtaulty.com/2016/02/16/windows-10-uwp-inkcanvas-and-rendertargetbitmap/

Comment: It would be awesome if you had answered this question a couple months ago, I managed to solve the problem by myself  :)